# Requiring peer dependency residing in host application with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Assume the following:

HelloWorldApp is a project built using Webpack and requires React.
MyReactComponent is a separate project used by HelloWorldApp and needs a reference to React in order to function.

From within MyReactComponent, I'm doing the following:

```
var react = require('react');
```

In MyReactComponent's package.json, I'm specifying React as a peerDependency.

Now, in order to bundle contents of a CSS file into MyReactComponent, I'm attempting to build MyReactComponent with Webpack.

How do I configure Webpack in the MyReactComponent project in such a way that when MyReactComponent calls for React (`require('react')`) that it will be given a reference to the React instance that's required in by HelloWorldApp?

I'm not sure if this is a supported workflow or if I'm thinking about it wrong. I know Webpack has an [`externals`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) configuration that seems like it would work if React were a global variable on window. In my case it is not a global variable; it is a module that HelloWorldApp `require`d in.

I also tried something like this inside MyReactComponent's Webpack configuration (which doesn't seem particularly documented):

```
externals: {
  "react": {
    root: "React",
    commonjs: "react"
    commonjs2: "react"
    amd: "react"
  }
}
```

But it always seems to return `undefined` instead of the React instance from HelloWorldApp. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if I configure Webpack for MyReactComponent like this:

```
externals: {
  "react": "require('react')"
}
```

That webpack creates a module like this in place of the actual React code:

```
/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = require("react");

/***/ },
```

HelloWorldApp `require`s MyReactComponent, so when HelloWorldApp's webpack process runs, it replaces the code above with:

```
/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = __webpack_require__(381);

/***/ }
```

With this in place, MyReactComponent now has access to HelloWorldApp's React.

This is working, but I'm assuming this isn't really an intended workflow. Am I crazy?

Comment: Did you ever figure out anything further on this?  I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: I ended up not using Webpack for MyReactComponent but instead just ran MyReactComponent through Babel (because the source was in es6) and the output is what I publish to npm. The `import` in the MyReactComponent source file is `import React from 'react';` and the output after going through Babel is `var _react = require('react');`. With this in place, HelloWorldApp requires/imports the Babel-compiled version of MyReactComponent, and, by so doing, MyReactComponent gets React from HelloWorldApp.

Comment: Hmm... I took a stab at trying this, and using Webpack's "externals" seemed to work fine for me.  I was using Angular, but I think the same concepts should apply.  In MyAngularComponent I specified `externals: { 'angular': 'angular' }` and had Angular 1.5.7 listed as a devDependency + peerDependency.  In my HelloWorldApp, I had Angular 1.5.6 saved as a regular dependency.  The require'd version of Angular from inside MyAngularComponent while running inside my HelloWorldApp then resolved to 1.5.6.  I'm still learning, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: I think using `externals` merely means that it will use `window.angular` when MyAngularComponent requires angular. I'm guessing your HelloWorldApp is loading angular and it's setting `window.angular`. But what do I know...

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what's happening.  I didn't realize I still had Angular being loaded as a script tag as well, which is why the externals thing "seemed" to be resolving, but once I removed that script tag so that it would only pull it from the require(), now I'm running into the same issue you had where the externals is now failing :(